# Need GitBlit groovy hook which push changed to other Gitblit server repo

Tags: java, git, groovy, gitblit

> Need a groovy push hook scripts from your Gitblit instance to another
>   Gitblit instance

I have two private `linux servers`, Say `A` and `B` with `GitBlit` install on both. All developers do commit and push their changes on server `A`, I want `B` keep in sync with `A`.

There is some `Groovy hook` but I am totally new in this, Can any one help to provide it.

PS: If There any push event found on `A` some script will fire and it `push` changes to `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks `james-moger`.

Base on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30837576/2478134) below are the snap of script.

```
File baseFolder = new File("/root/softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/gitblit/WEB-INF/data/git");
File repoFolder = new File(baseFolder, repository.name);
Git git = Git.open(repoFolder, FS.detect())
git.push().setRemote("ssh://admin@111.11.111.111:29418/testrepo.git").setPushAll().call();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you setup B to be a [mirror](http://gitblit.com/setup_mirrors.html) of A?

Comment: Both repository are private not public, As per document `you can Clone the external public repository as a mirror`

Comment: If I configure federation then Do I need to deal with SSH nd all  or federation will take care of it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure federation only uses the http/https transport.  This is a different mechanism than the standard mirror implementation.

Comment: under `Federation Proposals (Origin Gitblit Instance)` section see step2 `Select and click the propose link for the appropriate token on the federation page`, I can not find `propose link` anywere even I login using admin/admin rights

Comment: A = origin.  B = pulling. Skip using the web ui, configure it manually.http://gitblit.com/federation.html#H22

Comment: is Goovy push script not fulfill my requirement ?, Can you please help me to write groovy push script for this.

Comment: Just the repository changes.

Comment: Thanks!,  I have put my effor here can you please look into http://stackoverflow.com/q/30365265/2478134