# Not working: GitBlit groovy hook which push changed to other Gitblit server repo

Tags: git, github, groovy, ssh, gitblit

> Need a groovy push hook scripts which push changes from your Gitblit instance to another
>   Gitblit instance

I have two private `linux servers`, Say `A` and `B` with `GitBlit` install on both. All developers do commit and push their changes on server `A`, I want `B` keep in sync with `A`.

`A` : `ssh://admin@serverA:29418/testrepo.git`

Initially I have copied `testrepo` from server `A` to `B` using linux `scp command`

`B` : `ssh://admin@serverB:29418/testrepo.git`

`pushserver.groovy` :

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.TeamModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import com.gitblit.utils.StringUtils
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand.Result
import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils
import org.slf4j.Logger

File baseFolder = GitBlit.getFileOrFolder(Keys.git.repositoriesFolder)
File repoFolder = new File(baseFolder, repository.name);
Git git = Git.open(repoFolder, FS.detect())
git.push().setRemote("ssh://admin@serverB:29418/testrepo.git").setPushAll().call();
```

I have added this script using Gitblit UI

`testresopistory.git> edit> receive> post-receive scripts> selected(pushserver)`

Server restarted :
Now when I am going to push a file on `serverA` then why this script not push changes to `serverB` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [james-moger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830200/james-moger)

`Cheers!! :)` It's working with [pushhook](https://github.com/ankit337/GitBlit-groovy-Pushhook)

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.TeamModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import com.gitblit.utils.StringUtils
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand.Result
import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils
import org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS
import org.slf4j.Logger


logger.info("*************** START CUSTOM PUSH *******************")

File baseFolder = new File("/root/softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/gitblit/WEB-INF/data/git");
File repoFolder = new File(baseFolder, repository.name);
Git git = Git.open(repoFolder, FS.detect())
git.push().setRemote("ssh://admin@111.11.111.111:29418/testrepo.git").setPushAll().call();


logger.info("*************** DONE CUSTOM PUSH*******************")
```